# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

im trying to insert data into my stock table wich has 2 foreign keys and im getting this error, and i have no idea what im doing wrong.

this is my stock model.

```
//voorraad = stock
// Model Voorraad has the attributes, Aantal and Id;
// foreign keys are Producten_Id and Locaties_Id from the table Producten and locaties table

 class Voorraad extends Model
 {
   public $fillable = ['Id', 'aantal', 'Producten_Id', 'Locaties_Id'];
   protected $table = 'Voorraad';

public $timestamps = false;

public function producten()
{
    return $this->BelongsTo('App\Producten', 'Producten_Id');
}
public function locatie()
{
    return $this->BelongsTo('App\Locatie', 'Locaties_Id');
}
}
```

These are my controller function i use to create and store the data into the database.

```
public function create()
{      
    //retuning the view with database tables producten and locaties passing through to the create view the Id

    return view('voorraad.create',[
        'producten' => Producten::all('Id'), 
        'locaties' => Locatie::all('Id')
        ]);
} 

public function store(Request $request)
{

    //Producten_Id is the foreign key from the table producten
    //Locaties_Id is the foreign key form the table Locaties
    //aantal is the ammout of a sertain product

   Voorraad::create($request->only(['aantal', 'Producten_Id', 'Locaties_Id']));



   return redirect(Route('voorraad.index'));

}
```

and this is the create view

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'voorraad']) !!}

{!! Form::label('aantal', 'aantal:') !!}
{!! Form::text('aantal')!!} </br>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('producten_id', 'Producten_Id:') }}
    {{ Form::Select('Producten_Id' , $producten, null) }}</br>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('Locatie_Id', 'Id:') }}
    {{ Form::select('Locaties_Id', $locaties, null) }}
</div>      
    <div>
        {!! Form::Submit('create', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

{!! Form::close()!!}

if anyone can tell me what im doing wrong i would greatly appreciate it.
if there is anything i forgot to include just let me know and i'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a lot of stuff I would really recommend to change - but at first a look into that state.

Try to die and dump the data you try to extract from the request. Ensure that you really have all the data you expect to have. My first intenation tells me somethin is missing here.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->only(['aantal', 'Producten_Id', 'Locaties_Id']));
    ...
}
```

Even if you might manage to fix it with this I HIGHLY recommend you make major changes to your code.

```
public $fillable = ['Id', 'aantal', 'Producten_Id', 'Locaties_Id'];
```

NEVER ever make Id fillable. Users can change the Id or set the Id as they like to. Usually you do the same for foreign keys. You associate them as mentioned in the laravel docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

```
$user->account()->associate($account);
```

Dont make id's mass assignable!

When making these changes you will probably also easiy fix your foreign key problems.

Just a quick example

```
$p = Producten::findOrFail($request->input('Producten_Id'));
$l = Locatie::findOrFail($request->input('Locaties_Id'));

$v = new Voorraad();
$v->aantal = $request->input('aantal');
$v->locatie()->associate($l);
$v->producten()->associate($p);

$v->save();
```

By this you will ensure that $p and $l are valid values and it will fail otherwise.